# Xtext Elements Access

Tags: eclipse, xtext

I have written in Xtext:

```
grammar org.xtext.example.dsl.Dsl with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate dsl "http://www.xtext.org/example/dsl/Dsl"

Dsl :
    (elements += Type)*
;

Type:
    System
;

System:
    'The system' name = ID 'consists of the following:
;
```

And now I run the editor and type in a system name.
How can I acces the System name in my Eclipse file?

Comment: The question is a bit vague, what are you trying to do? Generally, Xtext's main interfaces (like the Generator, Validator etc.) give you a Resource that contains the AST of your file, which you can then inspect.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the soulution.

Write the following code in **src** folder in **org.example.somthing.generator** package  and class is Something.xtend (.xtend)

This is for code generation and it is generated by xtext. You will find doGenerate(Resource resource, IFileSystemAccess fsa) method write following code in that method..

> class DomainmodelGenerator implements IGenerator {
>
> > @Inject extension IQualifiedNameProvider
> >
> > > override void doGenerate(Resource resource, IFileSystemAccess fsa) {
> >
> > for(e: resource.allContents.toIterable.filter(DSL)) {
> >
> > > fsa.generateFile("abcd.txt",e.compile)
> >
> > }
> >
> > > > def compile(DSL d) '''
> >
> > «d.System.name»'''
> >     }

Now you have to write the main class to call the method of above class..

Here is the code...

public class Main {

```
@Inject
private Provider<ResourceSet> resourceSetProvider;

@Inject
private IResourceValidator validator;

@Inject
private IGenerator generator;

@Inject
private JavaIoFileSystemAccess fileAccess;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Injector injector = new DomainmodelStandaloneSetupGenerated()
            .createInjectorAndDoEMFRegistration();
    Main main = injector.getInstance(Main.class);
    main.runGenerator("sample.dmodel");
}

protected void runGenerator(String string) {
    // load the resource
    ResourceSet set = resourceSetProvider.get();
    Resource resource = set.getResource(URI.createURI(string), true);

    List<Issue> list = validator.validate(resource, CheckMode.ALL,
            CancelIndicator.NullImpl);
    if (!list.isEmpty()) {
        for (Issue issue : list) {
            System.err.println(issue);
        }
        return;
    }

    // configure and start the generator
    fileAccess.setOutputPath("output/");
    generator.doGenerate(resource, fileAccess);

    System.out.println("Code generation finished.");
}
```

}